# Why (int)(amount * 100) = 0 when amount = 0.01 in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
float amount = 0.01;
var result = (int)(amount * 100);
```

Why the result is 0, it should be 1.

Comment: Why not use double?

Comment: @AaronParrilla See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Interestingly, this [doesn't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bsI4Fm) on .NET 5, but [does reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4WEL0y) on .NET 4.7.

Comment: In .NET 4.7.2, it reproduces in the watch window, but not in the actual code being run.

Comment: `float amount = 0.01;` doesn't actually compile...

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @canton7 Maybe try in a release build